# Difference between «основной» and «основный»?

Tags: значения, выбор-слова

What's the difference between **основной** and **основный**?

They both seem to translate to "basic", although the first one seems to be more common.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Оснóвный** with stress on the second syllable is used only as technical or scientific term.

Оснóвная нить - beam thread

Оснóвный оксид - basic oxide

**Основнóй** is a regular word meaning **main, central, fundamental, basic**.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say is necessarily should have something to do with science or technology. It's much simpler. "Оснóвный" means "related to оснóва" (base, bottom, foundation).

The translation of основнóй above is correct.